# Restricting access to limited data extennsions in journey email test and preview

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions, permissions, user-management

I have a user role that has only permission to create and edit email in email studio but can't see any data extensions or subscriber data. But, now I have to give them access to journey builder and they should be able to test email from there. During that, they are able to view all customer data in data extensions, which is not good. Is there any way to restrict them to see only specific data extensions or folders in that space.
Thank you

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind is using shared dataextension for everything they should not be able to see and then restrict access to shared dataextensions.

Comment: That, or a separate business unit, which would probably not be a practical solution in many adhoc situations. That's pretty much it for data separation. Be careful: As of today, once you set something to "shared", be aware it becomes accessible for ALL BUs via SQL / AMPScript, SSJS regardless of sharing settings. You might not _see_ it on the UI, but you can query it or perform lookups. So be careful not to create another problem by fixing one.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately restricting the view only to a specific folder or Data extension not possible.
I will suggest planning your DE and user's roles according to the Business unit if you don't wanna show other business DE to other users.